# merging plotly graphs r

Tags: r, plotly, subplot

I am trying to merge different plotly plots in one view. The issue I am encountering is that the standard `subplot()` function merges the plots together. Is there a way to keep them separate as, for example, the `par(mfrow)` or the `grid.arrange()` function for ggplot?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`ggarrange()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.2/topics/ggarrange).

```
# Box plot (bp)
bxp <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
                 color = "dose", palette = "jco")
bxp
# Dot plot (dp)
dp <- ggdotplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len",
                 color = "dose", palette = "jco", binwidth = 1)

# Bar plot (bp)
bp <- ggbarplot(mtcars, x = "name", y = "mpg",
          fill = "cyl",               # change fill color by cyl
          color = "white",            # Set bar border colors to white
          palette = "jco",            # jco journal color palett. see ?ggpar
          sort.val = "asc",           # Sort the value in ascending order
          sort.by.groups = TRUE,      # Sort inside each group
          x.text.angle = 90           # Rotate vertically x axis texts
          )
bp + font("x.text", size = 8)
# Scatter plots (sp)
sp <- ggscatter(mtcars, x = "wt", y = "mpg",
                add = "reg.line",               # Add regression line
                conf.int = TRUE,                # Add confidence interval
                color = "cyl", palette = "jco", # Color by groups "cyl"
                shape = "cyl"                   # Change point shape by groups "cyl"
                )+
  stat_cor(aes(color = cyl), label.x = 3)       # Add correlation coefficient
sp

ggarrange(bxp, dp, bp + rremove("x.text"), 
          labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

Examples adopted from [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/)

Comment: Thank you for this, the problem in doing this is that i lose the interactivity that plotly offers.